# php how to go two level up on dirname(__FILE__)

Tags: php

I try to edit this project structure but I got error after I move files. help please

[image]

[image]

Comment: `dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
realpath(__DIR__ . "/..")
```